# Python: export point data to csv file with each column corresponding with the x, y, z coordinate

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv

x=[1,2,3,4,5] 
y=[2,3,4,5,6] 
z=[3,4,5,6,7]

data=[x,y,z]

out = csv.writer(open('myfile.csv',"w"), delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
out.writerows(zip(*data))
```

P(x, y, z) is three dimension point. Above arrays corresponds with x, y, z coordinate. Hence, there are five points in the space.

How can I export these points to csv file with each column corresponding with the x, y, z coordinate?

I need the detailed code example. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have, i.e. what isn't it doing?

Comment: The code can be run, but nothing occurs in my generating csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original file works fine, except you don't close the file.  If you run the file via a command prompt and Python exits it will probably close and flush the file, but running from a GUI may leave the file open and not flushed.

To fix the problem, use a `with` statement to close the file once the `with` scope is exited:

```
import csv

x=[1,2,3,4,5] 
y=[2,3,4,5,6] 
z=[3,4,5,6,7]

data=[x,y,z]

with open('myfile.csv','wb') as f:
    out = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    out.writerows(zip(*data))
```

Note binary mode `'wb'` should be used with the `csv` module.

Output:

```
"1","2","3"
"2","3","4"
"3","4","5"
"4","5","6"
"5","6","7"
```

If you are using an older version of Python without `with`, just assign the file to a variable and close it later:

```
f = open('myfile.csv','wb')
out = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
out.writerows(zip(*data))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work:

```
import csv

x = [1,2,3,4,5] 
y = [2,3,4,5,6] 
z = [3,4,5,6,7]

data = zip(x, y, z)

with open("filename.csv", "a") as f:
    coords = [map(str, tupl) for tupl in data]
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')

    for line in coords:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I run your code and obtain nothing from the dara.csv

Comment: @user3700852 The csv writer implementation I've left for you. But I'll  show you how to do, please wait.

Comment: How can I convert the array below to the list:                x=array([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])
y=array([[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]])
z=array([[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]])                                     x = [1,2,3,4,5] 
y = [2,3,4,5,6] 
z = [3,4,5,6,7]

Comment: @user3700852  I've just update my answer showing how to write in csv

Comment: It reports error:     writer.writerow(line)
_csv.Error: sequence expected

Comment: @user3700852 Are you using array from array module?

Comment: Yes, I am using array. Should I convert array to string or list?

Comment: I suggest you generate your sequences with lists and tuples instead of arrays in this case. Ultimately, why would you need arrays here?